# Using nodejs in the browser?

Tags: node.js, browser

Following my first question, I realized that the reason I couldn't get anything to work was that I was trying to use the `require()` method in the browser. In learning that this is not how Node works, I was confused. I understand now that Node is only a run-time environment that allows the use of JavaScript within the console. However, I'm still left with the question of how to achieve the functions of Node within the browser. (i.e. creating a button in the browser that creates a file using Node.) I've installed Browserify but I cannot find a good tutorial on how to use it. I'm very new to Computer Science so please forgive me for the redundant questions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Things do change. Apparently it will be possible to use node.js in the browser soon. You might be interested in this: [Run Node.js in the browser](https://blog.stackblitz.com/posts/introducing-webcontainers/)

Answer (score 0):

Node as you made the point is server-side runtime environment for js and the browser is client-side. Node.js has many useful built-in functionalities and they are not accessible in browser.

I recommend you to take a look how backend and frontend differs and how do they communicate with themselves. Then I think you will understand how to achieve creating a file by clicking a button in the browser.

Sorry I don't know anything about `browserify` but it would be better to learn node in cli.